# Classes not being removed from links under div dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a personal website.

In this site I would like to have the navigation links become active when I scroll to the part of the page relating to that navigation link, all other active links should then have the `nav-active` class removed.

I have it working partially, the navigation links are highlighting correctly. I do not understand why the active highlighting is not removed when the scrolling moves into the links that are under a div dropdown button.

Can anyone point me in the right direction and also point me to some tutorials/reading (not too advanced) on the relevant information about this issue?

My pen is here:

https://codepen.io/pjsmyth/pen/ZvaZBO/

Thanks in advance

Pete

Code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       
     var scrollLink = $('.scroll');
    
     // Smooth scrolling
     scrollLink.click(function(e) {
    
      e.preventDefault();
      $('body,html').animate({
       scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
      }, 1000 );
     });
    
      // Active link switching
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
        
        scrollLink.each(function() {
          
          var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20;
          
          if ( sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation ) {
            $(this).addClass('nav-active');
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('nav-active');
            $(this).children().removeClass('nav-active');
          }
        })
        
      })
    
    });
```

```css
/*
Fonts used in this site
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-family: 'Petit Formal Script', cursive;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Farsan', cursive;
font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
font-family: 'Yeseva One', cursive;
*/

/* CSS custom properties (variables) */
:root {
    --orange: #F9A828;
    --lightGrey: #ECECEB;
    --teal: #07617D;
    --darkGreyBlue: #2E383F;
    --darkGreyBlueTint: #718A9B;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    /*border: 1px red solid;*/
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

/*--------- Navigation Area ---------*/
body nav {
    height: 5vh;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlue);
    color: var(--lightGrey);
    z-index: 10;
}

.nav-active {
    color: var(--orange) !important;
    height: 5vh;
    /*border-width: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    float: right;*/
}

/*--------- Navigation Branding Area ---------*/
.branding {
    line-height: 5vh;
    float: left;
    height: 5vh;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

.branding i {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 1.6vh;
    color: var(--orange);
}

.branding div {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

/*--------- Navigation Links Area ---------*/
.navLinks {
    padding-right: 5%;
    float: right;
}

.navLinks a {
    line-height: 5vh;
    float: none;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
    padding: 0px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}



.dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
    line-height: 5vh;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: inherit;
    min-width: 75px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;

}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: var(--orange);
    padding: 0px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlue);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a {
    float: none;
    height: 5vh;
    line-height: 5vh;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlue);
    border-width: 0;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
    padding: 0 10px;

}

.navLinks a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    color: var(--orange);
    /*color: var(--darkGreyBlue);*/
}

/*--------- Splashscreen Area ---------*/
body div.splashScreen {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
    text-align: center;
}

body div.splashScreen div.splashText {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

body div.splashScreen div.splashText h1 {
    font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
    font-size: 7em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}

body div.splashScreen div.splashText a button {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid var(--lightGrey);
    color: var(--lightGrey);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

body div.splashScreen div.splashText a button:hover {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: var(--lightGrey);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
}

body div.splashScreen div.splashText a button:active {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
}

/*--------- About Area ---------*/
body div.aboutPage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--lightGrey);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 300;
    color: var(--darkGreyBlue);
}

body div.aboutPage header {
    padding-top: 7vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------- Experience Area ---------*/
body div.experiencePage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 300;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
}

body div.experiencePage header {
    padding-top: 7vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------- Skills Area ---------*/
body div.skillsPage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--lightGrey);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 300;
    color: var(--darkGreyBlue);
}

body div.skillsPage header {
    padding-top: 7vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------- Portfolio Area ---------*/
body div.portfolioPage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 300;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
}

body div.portfolioPage header {
    padding-top: 7vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------- Photography Area ---------*/
body div.photographyPage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--lightGrey);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 300;
    color: var(--darkGreyBlue);
}

body div.photographyPage header {
    padding-top: 7vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------- Favourites Area ---------*/
body div.favouritesPage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 300;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
}

body div.favouritesPage header {
    padding-top: 7vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Personal Website of Pete</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Farsan|Indie+Flower|Oleo+Script:700|Petit+Formal+Script|Raleway|Yeseva+One" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/71da83f6b4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/custom.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <!--  Start Navigation Section -->
    <nav>
        <span class="branding">
            <i class="fa fa-hand-peace-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <div>Pete Smyth</div>
        </span>
        <div class="navLinks">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Interests&nbsp<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a class="scroll" href="#bk-photography">Photography</a>
                    <a class="scroll" href="#bk-favourites">Favourites</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Resume&nbsp<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a class="scroll" href="#bk-resume-experience">Experience</a>
                    <a class="scroll" href="#bk-resume-skills">Skills</a>
                    <a class="scroll" href="#bk-resume-portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="scroll nav-active" href="#bk-splash">Home</a>
            <a class="scroll" href="#bk-about">About</a>

        </div>          
    </nav>
    <!--  End Navigation Section -->

    <!--  Start Splashscreen Section -->
    <div id="bk-splash" class="splashScreen">
        <div  class="splashText">
            <h1>
                Pete Smyth
            </h1>
            <a href="#bk-about"><button>Learn More</button></a>
        </div>
        <!-- end of splashText class -->
    </div>
    <!--  End Splashscreen Section -->

    <!--  Start About Section -->
    <div id="bk-about" class="aboutPage">
        <header>
            <h1>Here's the Goss</h1>
        </header>

    </div>
    <!--  End About Section -->

    <!--  Start Resume Experience Section -->
    <div id="bk-resume-experience" class="experiencePage">
        <header>
            <h1>Pete's Experiences</h1>
        </header>

    </div>
    <!--  End Resume Experience Section -->

    <!--  Start Resume Skills Section -->
    <div id="bk-resume-skills" class="skillsPage">
        <header>
            <h1>Pete's Skills</h1>
        </header>

    </div>
    <!--  End Resume Skills Section -->

    <!--  Start Portfolio Section -->
    <div id="bk-resume-portfolio" class="portfolioPage">
        <header>
            <h1>Pete's Portfolio</h1>
        </header>

    </div>
    <!--  End Portfolio Section -->

    <!--  Start Photography Section -->
    <div id="bk-photography" class="photographyPage">
        <header>
            <h1>Pete's Photography</h1>
        </header>

    </div>
    <!--  End Photography Section -->

    <!--  Start Favourites Section -->
    <div id="bk-favourites" class="favouritesPage">
        <header>
            <h1>Pete's Favourites</h1>
        </header>

    </div>
    <!--  End Favourites Section -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wish the `.dropbtn` to highlight when a `.scroll` under it is highlighted...

There could be a couple ways to do it.
But since the sections (div) have fixed offsets, you can get them all in an array, on load... And then compare them with the scrolled position.

When we have a "match", get its `id` from another array holding the ids and quit that loop right away.

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var scrollLink = $('.scroll');
  var dropbtn = $(".dropbtn");

  // Smooth scrolling
  scrollLink.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 1000 );
  });

  // Get all section position and id
  var sectionArr = [];
  var sectionId = [];
  $("body>div").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id") + " " + $(this).offset().top);
    sectionArr.push($(this).offset().top-20);
    sectionId.push($(this).attr("id"));
  });

  // Add the full page height to the array for the comparison of the last section
  sectionArr.push($("body").height());

  // Active link switching
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Remove the class everywhere
    scrollLink.removeClass('nav-active');
    dropbtn.removeClass('nav-active');

    // Compare the scrolled position with the offsets stored in array until we find.
    for(i=0;i<sectionArr.length;i++){
      var target = $(".scroll[href='#"+sectionId[i]+"']");

      // if the scrolled position is more than a section position, BUT less than the next
      if(scrollbarLocation>sectionArr[i] && scrollbarLocation<sectionArr[i+1]){
        // add the highlight class
        target.addClass("nav-active");
        if(target.parent().is(".dropdown-content")){
          // add the highlight class to the dropdown button
          target.closest(".dropdown").find(".dropbtn").addClass('nav-active');
        }
        break;  // Exit the loop on match
      }
    } // End for loop

  }); // End on scroll

}); // End ready
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/YYEMmM?editors=1011)

**Note** that you could adjust the "trigger point" so the menu highlighting occurs when more than the half of the section is displayed, which I really think would be nicer!

Just update this line:

```
sectionArr.push($(this).offset().top-20 - ($(this).height()/2));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your DOM is in the incorrect order. In your DOM, "About" is the last DOM element with `.scroll`, and since About is also valid for `sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation` and is the last item to be processed it overwrites the class manipulation for the other navigation elements that are on screen.

I partially fixed it [in this demo here](https://codepen.io/yangshun/pen/YYEbwo?editors=1010).

Comment: Needing the elements to be in a particular order on the page in order for this to work seems really brittle to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional selection logic is a little confused. The way you have it set up now, if the `sectionOffset` is less than the `scrollbarLocation` then you try to set the `nav-active` class on the current link and remove it from the siblings, children and parent links.

The problem is that if the current link is itself a *child* link, then the links you want to unset are going to be siblings of the link, **siblings of the parent** of the link or **children of the siblings of the parent** link.

You could cover all of those cases manually, but then your code becomes convoluted and brittle. What if, at some point in the future, you want to add additional layers of link nesting? You'd have to manually account for that.

Luckily, since you're already looping through all of your links on a scroll event, there's an easier way. Just check to see if a section has scrolled off of the screen and remove the `nav-active` class of it's associated link by changing your `each` callback:

```
scrollLink.each(function() {

  var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20;
  var sectionBottom = sectionOffset + $(this.hash).height();

  if ( sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation && sectionBottom >= scrollbarLocation) {
    $(this).addClass('nav-active');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('nav-active');
  }
})
```

[Updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/bmceldowney/pen/XVzwpY)

Here it is as a snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
 var scrollLink = $('.scroll');

 // Smooth scrolling
 scrollLink.click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  $('body,html').animate({
   scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
  }, 1000 );
 });

  // Active link switching
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    scrollLink.each(function() {
      
      var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20;
      var sectionBottom = sectionOffset + $(this.hash).height();
      
      if ( sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation && sectionBottom >= scrollbarLocation) {
        $(this).addClass('nav-active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('nav-active');
      }
    })
    
  })

});
```

```css
/*
Fonts used in this site
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-family: 'Petit Formal Script', cursive;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Farsan', cursive;
font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
font-family: 'Yeseva One', cursive;
*/

/* CSS custom properties (variables) */
:root {
    --orange: #F9A828;
    --lightGrey: #ECECEB;
    --teal: #07617D;
    --darkGreyBlue: #2E383F;
    --darkGreyBlueTint: #718A9B;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    /*border: 1px red solid;*/
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

/*--------- Navigation Area ---------*/
body nav {
    height: 5vh;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlue);
    color: var(--lightGrey);
    z-index: 10;
}

.nav-active {
    color: var(--orange) !important;
    height: 5vh;
    /*border-width: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    float: right;*/
}

/*--------- Navigation Branding Area ---------*/
.branding {
    line-height: 5vh;
    float: left;
    height: 5vh;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

.branding i {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 1.6vh;
    color: var(--orange);
}

.branding div {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

/*--------- Navigation Links Area ---------*/
.navLinks {
    padding-right: 5%;
    float: right;
}

.navLinks a {
    line-height: 5vh;
    float: none;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
    padding: 0px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}



.dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
    line-height: 5vh;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: inherit;
    min-width: 75px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;

}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: var(--orange);
    padding: 0px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlue);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a {
    float: none;
    height: 5vh;
    line-height: 5vh;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlue);
    border-width: 0;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
    padding: 0 10px;

}

.navLinks a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    color: var(--orange);
    /*color: var(--darkGreyBlue);*/
}

/*--------- Splashscreen Area ---------*/
body div.splashScreen {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
    text-align: center;
}

body div.splashScreen div.splashText {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

body div.splashScreen div.splashText h1 {
    font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
    font-size: 7em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}

body div.splashScreen div.splashText a button {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid var(--lightGrey);
    color: var(--lightGrey);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

body div.splashScreen div.splashText a button:hover {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: var(--lightGrey);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
}

body div.splashScreen div.splashText a button:active {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
}

/*--------- About Area ---------*/
body div.aboutPage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--lightGrey);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 300;
    color: var(--darkGreyBlue);
}

body div.aboutPage header {
    padding-top: 7vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------- Experience Area ---------*/
body div.experiencePage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 300;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
}

body div.experiencePage header {
    padding-top: 7vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------- Skills Area ---------*/
body div.skillsPage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--lightGrey);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 300;
    color: var(--darkGreyBlue);
}

body div.skillsPage header {
    padding-top: 7vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------- Portfolio Area ---------*/
body div.portfolioPage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 300;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
}

body div.portfolioPage header {
    padding-top: 7vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------- Photography Area ---------*/
body div.photographyPage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--lightGrey);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 300;
    color: var(--darkGreyBlue);
}

body div.photographyPage header {
    padding-top: 7vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------- Favourites Area ---------*/
body div.favouritesPage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--darkGreyBlueTint);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size: 300;
    color: var(--lightGrey);
}

body div.favouritesPage header {
    padding-top: 7vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Personal Website of Pete</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Farsan|Indie+Flower|Oleo+Script:700|Petit+Formal+Script|Raleway|Yeseva+One" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/71da83f6b4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/custom.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <!--  Start Navigation Section -->
    <nav>
        <span class="branding">
            <i class="fa fa-hand-peace-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <div>Pete Smyth</div>
        </span>
        <div class="navLinks">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Interests&nbsp<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a class="scroll" href="#bk-photography">Photography</a>
                    <a class="scroll" href="#bk-favourites">Favourites</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Resume&nbsp<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a class="scroll" href="#bk-resume-experience">Experience</a>
                    <a class="scroll" href="#bk-resume-skills">Skills</a>
                    <a class="scroll" href="#bk-resume-portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="scroll nav-active" href="#bk-splash">Home</a>
            <a class="scroll" href="#bk-about">About</a>

        </div>          
    </nav>
    <!--  End Navigation Section -->

    <!--  Start Splashscreen Section -->
    <div id="bk-splash" class="splashScreen">
        <div  class="splashText">
            <h1>
                Pete Smyth
            </h1>
            <a href="#bk-about"><button>Learn More</button></a>
        </div>
        <!-- end of splashText class -->
    </div>
    <!--  End Splashscreen Section -->

    <!--  Start About Section -->
    <div id="bk-about" class="aboutPage">
        <header>
            <h1>Here's the Goss</h1>
        </header>

    </div>
    <!--  End About Section -->

    <!--  Start Resume Experience Section -->
    <div id="bk-resume-experience" class="experiencePage">
        <header>
            <h1>Pete's Experiences</h1>
        </header>

    </div>
    <!--  End Resume Experience Section -->

    <!--  Start Resume Skills Section -->
    <div id="bk-resume-skills" class="skillsPage">
        <header>
            <h1>Pete's Skills</h1>
        </header>

    </div>
    <!--  End Resume Skills Section -->

    <!--  Start Portfolio Section -->
    <div id="bk-resume-portfolio" class="portfolioPage">
        <header>
            <h1>Pete's Portfolio</h1>
        </header>

    </div>
    <!--  End Portfolio Section -->

    <!--  Start Photography Section -->
    <div id="bk-photography" class="photographyPage">
        <header>
            <h1>Pete's Photography</h1>
        </header>

    </div>
    <!--  End Photography Section -->

    <!--  Start Favourites Section -->
    <div id="bk-favourites" class="favouritesPage">
        <header>
            <h1>Pete's Favourites</h1>
        </header>

    </div>
    <!--  End Favourites Section -->
</body>
```